# How to use where like clause in prisma?

Tags: prisma

I have three models in which one of it is the parent (`School`).

```
model Student {
  school     School
  firstname  string
  lastname   string
}

model Teacher {
  school  School
  name    string
}

model School {
  students  Student[]
  teachers  Teacher[]
}
```

The goal is to get a list of students and teachers at a school by searching their names.

I now have a practical answer. However, I believe there is still a quicker way to do this.
I simply want to know if this can be accomplished with a single query.

```js
const query = "Doe"

const school  = ....
const teachers = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM Teacher WHERE name LIKE '%${query}%'`;
const students = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM Student WHERE firstname LIKE '%${query}%' AND lastname LIKE '%${query}%' `;

return {
    ...school,
    teachers,
    students
}
```

Comment: I am wondering if you can use a UNION operator to combine the result set of two SELECT statements.

Comment: Would a UNION Sql query work for you? I can try creating a union query.

Comment: @NurulSundarani yes we can try union.